# MySQLTuner 1.5 Maximum possible memory usage conflicting information

Tags: mysql, memory, mysqltuner

We host on a VPS with 16gb Memory allocated and 12 processes, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5649 @ 2.53GHz

Only recently when using mysqltuner.pl, it is showing the following which has only started since the server when down for a day, a month or so ago. Our memory fills up and the swap hits 100%.

Free -m

```
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
 Mem:         15850      15498        352          1        891       8208
-/+ buffers/cache:       6397       9452 
 Swap:          510        510          0
```

after flush memory

```
Mem:         15850       3053      12796          0          3         63
-/+ buffers/cache:       2986      12864 
Swap:          510         51        459
```

mysqltuner shows using over 600% of the installed ram which should only read about 60%

```
[--] Total buffers: 9.2G global + 1.9M per thread (300 max threads)
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 9.3G (601.06% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 9.8G (630.04% of installed RAM)
```

Our server administrators stated that they are going to rebuild the swap partition and reinsert and check the main drive for errors.

Any suggestions/help would be great just so that I have a clearer understanding, we have been saying there is a problem for ages.

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/issues/104

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Last version is fixing this issue.
https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/issues/104

We have change the way mysqltuner collect memory information.
/proc/meminfo is now used and it seems to be better and avoid (10 digits memory cut from mem command.)